# Can GNU Make be coerced into being more specific about what dependencies are actually missing?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am using GNU-Make (v4+) to build some very complicated projects. The dependency tree for any given target might be 5-10 levels deep, and most of those levels involve lots of pattern matching rules. I'm starting to get annoyed while debugging this because it seems error reporting only gives me the least useful bit of information when something is missing.

For example, consider a couple levels of dependencies:

```
.PHONY: out
out: thing_a thing_b

thing_%: %
    cat $< > $@

a:
    touch $@

clean:
    rm -f thing_a thing_b a b
```

Note that `make out` will fail because there is no file `b` and no way to automatically make it. If you `touch b` it will work. This makes `b` the ultimate culprit that is missing, but that's not what the error message will say:

> make: *** No rule to make target 'thing_b', needed by 'out'.  Stop.

This is not helpful, because there is a target rule for `thing_b`, it just happens to be a pattern rule that is itself missing a dependency.

Is there any way to get make to output a more detailed report of what is actually missing that would fulfill the dependencies at a lower level?

Comment: `make -d` may help, but I agree that the error message is unhelpful.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I've been aware of `make -d`, and indeed the file names that are the _real_ offending missing dependencies are in the output text, but nothing seems to identify the lines any differently from ones that exist and are found. This makes the output only useful to somebody that can hand check each line and compare it with the file system knowing what should and shouldn't exist. This debug process is painful and I've been hoping to automate it a bit.

Comment: This is a horrible kludge, but it might work: `make -dr | grep pattern | tail -1`

Comment: What happens if you give the pattern also as an order-only prerequisite?

Comment: @Vroomfondel Nothing useful.

Comment: The only chance I see to mitigate this problem is to move away from pattern rules to creating explicit dependencies - this doesn't necessarily mean to write them all out by hand, but a bit of GNUmake programming will be inevitable.